# Gradle task dependency only for rootProject in allprojects section

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

I got a gradle task to build docker images for all my projects. These run fine except for the `rootProject` which has a dependent task to be executed before the `DockerimageBuild itself. This dependency should only apply for the`rootProject` and not the subprojects.
I googled extensively and read the docs but didn't find the perfect solution to add a dependency, probably i am missing a obvious point.

This is my task (stripped out some of the gradle file).

```
allprojects {
apply plugin: com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.DockerRemoteApiPlugin
    repositories { jcenter() }

docker {
    registryCredentials {
            username = dockerRegistryUsername
            password = dockerRegistryPassword
    }
}

// task build_DockerImage(type: DockerBuildImage, dependsOn: [copy_ImageSource, prepare_ImageConfig]) {
task build_DockerImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    group 'Docker'
    description "Builds the docker image: ${dockerTag} locally"
    println "Project: ${rootProject.projectDir}/ci/images/${project.name}"
    inputDir = file("${rootProject.projectDir}/ci/images/${project.name}")
    tag = "azeti/${project.name}:${dockerTag}"
}
```

It should have `dependsOn: copy_ImageSource` but i can't figure out the right notation for it.

Thanks for your help. 
Regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as simple as comparing the current project's name with the ones of the root project and only applying `dependsOn`for a match.

I have stripped out rest of the code for the sake of simplicity, check the if condition.

```
task build_DockerImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
    group 'Docker'
    description "Builds the docker image: ${dockerTag} locally"
    if(project.name.equals(rootProject.name) ) {
        dependsOn copy_ImageSource
    }
    inputDir = file("${rootProject.projectDir}/ci/images/${project.name}")
    tag = "azeti/${project.name}:${dockerTag}"
}
```